# Can't get Bootstrap Modal contact form to open when clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, contacts

I'm new to web development and it's my first post on stack overflow, I'm trying to follow a guide from http://untame.net/2013/05/how-to-build-a-modal-contact-form-in-twitter-bootstrap-with-php-ajax/   to create a Bootstrap modal contact form when a button is clicked on my website. It's exactly what I need and the tutorial is simple enough but I just can't get it to work. When I click the button, nothing happens, no modal pop up. I even downloaded their source code and the same thing happens. No errors show and all libraries load correctly.

Any advice would be amazing thanks ! Code is all on the tutorial linked. Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Please create a bootply with your problem and provide us with your code. Without this it's impossible to help.

Comment: And post your actual code here. StackOverflow doesn't allow linking to code without also including it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you're missing a `data-target` attribute in the anchor element:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#form-content" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
```

Check [the Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples) for more thorough information.